# How to get URL's Title?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
if ($link == true) {
    // Links
    $link_search = '/\[a\](.*?)\[\/a\]/i';

    if (preg_match_all($link_search, $text, $matches)) {

        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            $match_decode = urldecode($match);
            $match_url = $match_decode;

            if (!preg_match("/http\:\/\//", $match_decode)) {
                $match_url = 'http://' . $match_url;
            }

            $text = str_replace('[a]' . $match . '[/a]', '<a href="' . strip_tags($match_url) . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . $match_decode . '</a>', $text);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code displays the link posted and when clicked redirects to the link. What I want is to show the  of the destination link. For ex. Stackoverflow is shown in the post and when clicked takes user to http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: This will require retrieving the page and parsing out its `<title>` tag. If the target site is slow to load, your page will be too - and if you have many links...

Comment: So, how do I do it? Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$text = str_replace('[a]' . $match . '[/a]', '<a href="' . strip_tags($match_url) . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . $match_decode . '</a>', $text);
```

with:

```
$str = file_get_contents($match_url);
preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
$text = str_replace('[a]' . $match . '[/a]', '<a href="' . strip_tags($match_url) . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . $title[1] . '</a>', $text);
```

to get images:

```
preg_match("/\<img\>(.*)\<\/img\>/",$str,$img);
```

You will get an array in $img, you will have to loop through it:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($img); $i++){
    echo $img[$i];
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but can you tell me if there's a way to extract excerpt or a image(if the page has any)? Thank you.

Comment: use preg_match("/\<img\>(.*)\<\/img\>/",$str,$img);

Comment: How do I make the image appear below the link? Please tell me what to add and where to. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ranger19 search on existing or create a new question and show what you tried and it didnt work